# Building a New PC, Motherboard Not Responding to Power Supply

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, computer-building, build

I have recently purchased a new PC. I have verified that the power supply works (using the on-board button). The motherboard is not powering on. I have verified connections (unplugging and plugging back in), I have verified that the CPU is sitting correctly (unseated and replaced).

The only feedback I get is a blinking red light in the very top left corner of the motherboard when the ATX CPU 8-pin connection is disconnected (which I assume is just telling me that the CPU has no power.

The motherboard does have a trouble sheet LED's but none are lit up. I also do not get the RGB Lights on the motherboard.

I have the following parts:

Motherboard: ASUS ROG Strix X570-E
CPU: AMD Ryzen 9 3900X
PSU: CORSAIR AXi Series, AX 1200i
RAM: 2x Corsair Dominator Platinum RGB DDR4 3200
SSD: Samsung SSD 860 Pro 2TB
GPU: Sapphire Radeon Nitro+ Rx 5700 Xt
CASE: Cooler Master Cosmos C700P Black Edition
CPU Cooler: Cooler Master MasterLiquid ML360R

The one of the only things I can think of is that the everything is working correctly, but I do not have the case buttons wired correctly.

Let me know if there is any more additional information needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: WhenI had this problem with my most recent build, one of the CPU socket pins was bent connecting ground to VCC, CPU was installed correctly.  Had to RMA the board.

Comment: "I do not have the case buttons wired correctly." - You really should do this.